# calling popToRootViewController on the main thread after network callback is not working

Tags: ios, swift, mvp

When a user sends its register form, I am trying to popToRootViewController who is a login screen. To achieve this, I have a delegation callback when server side response is success. The problem is that if I call the popToRoot... method during the delegation callback, the current viewController is not poped.

RegisterView->RegisterPresenter->NetworkManager
NetworkManager->PresenterInput->RegisterView->RegisterPresenter->RegisterWireframe(call popToRootViewController over RegisterView)

On my Wireframe:

```
    extension RegisterRouter: RegisterRouterProtocol {
    func presentLoginBack(from: RegisterViewProtocol) {
        if let vc = from as? UIViewController {
            DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                vc.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On networkLayer:

```
guard (200...207) ~= status else {
                    if status == 210 {
                        self.presenterInputDelegate?.notifyEndRegisterSuccess()
                    }
```

Comment: Can you check that either of those are not nil `vc, presenterInputDelegate, navigationController`. Also does your code goes into this flow: `if status == 210 {` ? Any console warnings?

Comment: Hi vpoltave, I have this warning: popToViewController:transition: called on <UINavigationController 0x126844c00> while an existing transition or presentation is occurring; the navigation stack will not be updated.

Comment: May the UIActivityIndicatorView is interfering. Also all components ar not null

Comment: Yes it can. Try to dismiss presented `viewController` first, before pop

Comment: vpoltave, the problem was a success alert that I present when the callback from networking is ok. So I set an alert action to call the "RegisterPresenter.presentLoginView()". Now is working

Answer (score 0):

As vpoltave mentioned, there was a warning:

```
popToViewController:transition: called on <UINavigationController 0x126844c00> while an existing transition or presentation is occurring; the navigation stack will not be updated.
```

This one made me aware that I was presenting an alert in the main thread as the same time that I was performing the popToViewController transition.

So, the solution was to carry out the popToViewController when the user dismiss the alert.